# How to add the same object to different Panels in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, label, flowlayout

I am new in c#, I was wandering why if I try to add the same object to different FlowLayoutPanel, it is displayed only on the last Panel.

Example:

```
Label noElementsTitleLabel = LabelFactory.getLabel("No elements");

private void loadLabelsInPanel(FlowLayoutPanel panel, Label title, Label[] labelArray)
{
    panel.Controls.Add(title);
    if (labelArray.Length == 0)
    {
        panel.Controls.Add(noElementsTitleLabel);
        return;
    }            
    panel.Controls.AddRange(labelArray);
}
```

If I call `loadLabelsInPanel` three times giving three different layout panels and `labelArray` is always empty, I can see the `noElementsTitleLabel` only in the third panel

Comment: `noElementsTitleLabel` is a Control, it can have only one Parent. It would probably be different with `panel.Controls.Add(LabelFactory.getLabel("No elements"));`. This assuming `LabelFactory` returns a new object each time.

Comment: A control has four properties 1) Left 2) Top 3) Width 4) Height  You are not setting these properties so they are defaulting and the two panels are located in the same place.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Jimi, i forgot that Label was a Control!